# How can i separate a column from a Map in deluge?

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I am using Zoho deluge to write a function. I actually call an API and I get the following response:

```
 [
  {"name": "abc", email: "abc@xyz.com" },
  {"name": "qwc", email: "qwc@mnh.com" }
 ]
```

I have converted it into the JSONArray (Map). However, I do not want to run a loop to get email values because there are 10k entries.
Could anyone please help me to extract the email column from the response?

Answer (score 1):

Only way i know(for deluge) is to use a loop. Unfortunately Zoho interrupts a Function after 40 loops(Guess it was 40). Do you have any option to give the API parameters to filter for the values you need?(In Zoho it is possible)

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the email column can probably be done using Deluge's executeXpath() function which seems to work on Deluge-Maps, and Json as well as XML data.

Here is an example:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Recreate the example data structure from the question.
//----------------------------------------------------------------
response = list(
  {"name": "abc", email: "abc@xyz.com" },
  {"name": "qwc", email: "qwc@mnh.com" }
 );

my_data = {"my_list": response};

//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Extract raw email data that will include field separator: "-|-"
//----------------------------------------------------------------
raw_email_data = my_data.executeXpath("/root/my_list/email/text()");

//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Remove the field separator: "-|-"
// This should result in a list: "abc@xyz.com", "qwc@mnh.com",...
//----------------------------------------------------------------
email_list = raw_email_data.toList("-|-");
```